# Chrome Extension Inject into iFrame with JavaScript

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy

I'm working on a Chrome Extension that allows a user to open a site into an iframe in a new tab. My goal is to allow them to modify the CSS by injecting the code via JavaScript from the parent window, yet I'm getting blocked by origin-only issues.

Is there a way around this? I know I've seen other extensions do similar things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript
```

with `allFrames` set to `true`

Documentation can be found here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript

This will allow you to inject a content script into a page and all iFrames in that page. There is also a similar function for injecting CSS : )